# What is the VBA equivalent of using an array formula to calculate the max non-blank value of a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, spreadsheet, microsoft-office-2019

I have the following array formula in Excel: {=MAX((C9:C44<>"")*(ROW(C9:C44)))} that calculates and returns the row number of the last non-blank cell in a range.
I could reference the result in that cell in VBA, but I want to know the methodology to calculate it without using that reference.

I've tried WorksheetFunction.Max("C9:C44" <> "") * Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, but then I'm not sure how to return it as an array result.  I tried using the FormulaArray property, but I don't know if that is intended to work the way I want it to.

To re-iterate, I'm just looking for the VBA equivalent of =MAX((C9:C44<>"")*(ROW(C9:C44))).

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: @ScottCraner While your XY comment is spot on, I'm actually interested in an answer to the question as well...

Comment: @AlexM if you want to do array formulas in vba, use `Worksheet.Evaluate`.  outside a few exceptions, it is better to use native vba.